# How to set WPF window position in secondary display

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, media-player, mediaelement

I have two displays. I want to make a media player and I want to play video full screen on my secondary display. So I’m trying to make a media player using WPF

Here is the code so far I wrote

```
Screen[] _screens = Screen.AllScreens;
System.Drawing.Rectangle ractagle = _screens[1].Bounds;
//player is  my window
player.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
player.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;

player.Left = ractagle.X;
player.Top = ractagle.Y;


// MediaControl is an media elements
MediaControl.Height = ractagle.Height;
MediaControl.Width = ractagle.Width;
```

But somehow it’s just playing on my first display. 
Any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `WindowStartupLocation` is set to `Manual` for the form you are displaying

Otherwise nothing you do will have any effect on the position of the window.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
// reference System.Drawing
//

Screen s = Screen.AllScreens[1];

System.Drawing.Rectangle r  = s.WorkingArea;
Me.Top = r.Top;
Me.Left = r.Left;
```

This header of the XAML of the Window I used.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="823" WindowStartupLocation="Manual">
    <Canvas Width="743">
        //Controls etc
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: hey its not working, I double checked, I set the WindowStartupLocation Manual

Comment: I knocked up a small sample to demonstrate and it works for me. What isn't working? See edit for the XAML I used.

Comment: Nice solution. However it only gives you a full screen window on the secondary screen (you still see the windows border etc.). In case someone else stumbles over this post and wants complete full screen I found the solution here: http://mostlytech.blogspot.de/2008/01/maximizing-wpf-window-to-second-monitor.html

Answer (score 9):

5 years later! But for anyone else that stumbles across this as I did ...

If you can't or do not want to add the entire System.Windows.Forms dll reference, you can use [WpfScreenHelper](https://github.com/micdenny/WpfScreenHelper) by [micdenny](https://github.com/micdenny) (search in NuGet)

```
  Screen screen = WpfScreenHelper.AllScreens[0];
  Left = screen.Bounds.Left;
  Top = screen.Bounds.Top;
  Width = screen.Bounds.Width;
  Height = screen.Bounds.Height;
```

Micdenny has ported the Windows Forms Screen helper for WPF. This is excellent when you have other WPF refs that do not play nice with Forms (Like WPF Live-Charts).

Comment: Not working for me, I had to change the code for it to compile. (ex: Screen screen = Screen.AllScreens.ToList<Screen>()[0]; ...). Anyway, the change of index 0 to 1 didn't have an effect. Is something else needed for it to work? I installed the 0.3.0 (current version) of WpfScreenHelper.

Comment: @ExelGamboa Sorry it is not working for you. In my case, Nuget installed fine. I then built a ScreenManager class that only uses WpfScreenHelper and generic collections. I have "public List<Screen> Screens;" which I populate in the constructor with "Screens = new List<Screen>(Screen.AllScreens);" I then created a method "public Screen GetScreen(int index){ return Screens[index]; }", I then position and size the App with a Rect populated from returned "screen.Bounds". I had no build issues at all. What else have you installed / referenced? Perhaps there is a conflict somewhere?

Comment: Maybe that's true. Thanks for the detail, I will try it again like that and check if I did something different.

Comment: There can be problems with this approach if the secondary monitor has a different scale ratio or DPI to the primary monitor. On identical displays this works perfectly, though.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following in VS 2019:

```
private void MaximizeToSecondaryScreen()
{
    this.Left = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft;
    this.Top = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop;
    this.Height = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;
    this.Width = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
}
```

Comment: This is useful to know, some of the previous answers around this topic don't work if additional monitors are a different size and have a different DPI / scale factor.

Comment: This worked for me but if your screens have different refresh rates it will cause the Canvas to lag.

Answer (score 3):

My solution combines the ideas and ensures, that secondary screen is there:

```
using System.Linq;
// ...
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {                
        InitializeComponent();

        var screens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;
        var firstSecondary = screens.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Primary == false);
        if (firstSecondary != null)
        {
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual; 
            // Ensure Window is minimized on creation
            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            // Define Position on Secondary screen, for "Normal" window-mode
            // ( Here Top/Left-Position )
            Left = firstSecondary.Bounds.Left;
            Top = firstSecondary.Bounds.Top;
        }            
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }    

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Maximize after position is defined in constructor
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set the window to maximized immediately, it wont work.
Use the loaded event and you wont need Windows Forms

```
var secondaryScreenLeft = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;

window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
window.Left = secondaryScreenLeft ;
window.Top = 0;
window.Loaded += Window_Loaded;

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var senderWindow = sender as Window;
    senderWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```