# Set which monitor WPF app launches on during debug session

Tags: c#, wpf, multiple-monitors

I have 3 monitors and when I launch a debug session, the WPF app automatically starts 2 screens away from where I am coding. I found the code to specify where on the screen it starts:

```
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
        Left = 100;
        Top = 100;
```

but not how to control which monitor it starts on. Since it isn't a Windows Forms app, I can't do something like:

```
var myApp = InitializeComponent();
```

So I am not sure what to do next to get control of the window.

Comment: Say `Left = 2020;`

Comment: Thanks Rand, using `Left = -4500; Top = -1000;` works, but it seems like there should be a "right" way to send it to a specific monitor, like the one that VS is running on.

Comment: Have a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972044/how-to-set-wpf-window-position-in-secondary-display